# Ionic remove failed due to Bower is not installed?

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I got this error when I want to delete my Ionic folder

[image]

I tried to delete it manually but it seems blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Try running npm install bower -g first

Comment: installing bower doesn't work or your original problem?